# Saving Keras model wrapped inside pipeline

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, pipeline

Is there a way to save a Keras model (using pickle, joblib, model.to_json() or tf.keras.models.save_model) that has been incorporated into an sklearn or imblearn pipeline via a scikit-learn wrapper such as `KerasClassifier`?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have similar situation for a Sklearn.Pipeline.pipeline object

Comment: Nope. Not yet. To tell you the truth i have kind of dropped it, since i am studying for the AWS developer associate certification exam. I do understand though, that the solution is something like serializing the trained model piecemeal...